# Contar elementos de numeros de un regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Tengo esta funcion regex :`/^\d+\.\d{2}(\,\d+\.\d{2}){0,}$/` consiste en que solo se pueden digitar numeros de esta forma separados por comas:  `2.00, 200.00, 23.40` tengo que imprimir el numero de valores que hay, tomando el ejemplo me tendria que imprmir que hay 3 valores, ya que el 2.00 es un valor, el 200.00 es otro valor y asi sucesivamente, no tiene que contar las comas.

Comment: Hace falta más contexto en tu código. Cómo se ejecuta la expresión regular y dónde se almacena.

Answer (score 1):

No puedes utilizar esa expresión regular y a su vez intentar contar el número de ocurrencias porque esa expresión regular valida todo el string como un todo. Desde el inicio del mismo hasta el final.

Para poder contar las ocurrencias deberías tener una expresión regular que únicamente buscase los números 'sueltos' y utilizase el modificador global `g`.

Por ejemplo (aunque, ojo, **no sirve para tu caso**)

```
(?<=^|,)\d+\.\d{2}(?=,|$)
```

Esa expresión regular va capturando los números "de uno en uno". Con lo que podrías contar el número de ocurrencias de tu objeto match para saber la cantidad de ocurrencias que has tenido.

```js
const regex = /(?<=^|,)\d+\.\d{2}(?=,|$)/g;
const str = `2.00,200.00,23.40`;

var count = (str.match(regex) || []).length;
console.log(`Cantidad: ` + count);
```

Ojo que este ejemplo no funciona para tu caso porque no valida **todo** el string como algo completo. Por lo tanto encuentra números correctos e ignora cosas que son incorrectas, lo cual probablemente no es lo que quieres.

Hay maneras de hacer algo similar y que a la vez valide el string de manera completa, pero no con javascript. Para ello necesitaríamos otros motores de expresión regular más potentes, como PCRE. Con ellos se podrían utilizar `\G` y `\K` para conseguirlo. Pero no podemos con javascript.

Así que la única forma que se me ocurre (y que a su vez es sencilla) es que una vez que hayas validado el string cuentes el número de comas.

Como has validado el string, sabes que el formato es correcto y que no vas a poder encontrar comas en posiciones que no te esperas, únicamente separando números. Así que cuentas las comas, sumas 1 y así obtienes la cantidad de números que hay:

```js
const regex = /^\d+\.\d{2}(?:,\d+\.\d{2}){0,}$/;
const str = `2.00,200.00,23.40`;

let m;
if ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    console.log( `Cantidad: ` + ( 1 + (str.match(/,/g)||[]).length ) );
}
```

**NOTA1:** En las expresiones regulares no es necesario escapar las comas. Así que en lugar de poner `\,` lo mejor sería poner simplemente `,`

**NOTA2:** Si no vas a capturar el contenido del grupo, se recomienda utilizar grupos de no-captura en lugar de captura.

Los grupos de no-captura tienen esta forma

```
(?: lo que sea )
```

Mientras que los grupos de captura (como el que has usado) tienen esta forma:

```
( lo que sea )
```